# what is the difference between running Testng tests with Gradle task and test?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle, testng

I've started using Gradle recently. As I found, the `TestNG` can be used in two ways. one way is by using **Gradle** `task` like this:

```
task runTests(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: 'classes') {
    main = 'org.testng.TestNG'
    classpath = files("./src/test/resources/RunTestng.xml",
            sourceSets.main.compileClasspath,
            sourceSets.test.compileClasspath,
            sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath,
            sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath)
    args = ["./src/test/resources/RunTestng.xml"]
}
```

and the other way is using a **Gradle** `test` like this:

```
test{
    useTestNG(){
        suites './src/test/resources/RunTestng.xml'
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }
}
```

**My question:** what are the differences or advantages of using one of these two ways?

It would be great if you correct my mistake and thanks for any clarification :)

Comment: The `test` task is "built-in" (by the `java` plugin, I believe) and is already configured for the common use cases. Your task is created by you and has to be "manually" configured. Plus, the `test` task has a type of `Test` whereas yours is a `JavaExec`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, is there any advantages in using any of them? or it's not  that much important which one to use?

Comment: Unless needed otherwise, use `test`. It's standard.